# how to delete all selected tasks in todo list reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i am new to reactjs and i am trying to make a todolist, in which i can delete all selected tasks at once. though i am able to delete each task one by one but can't figure out how to pass index or id of selected tasks in delete method. i have added that button in the end of my code. so can anyone help me to find out that how can i pass selected task's index or id to button's deleted method? and is there any possibility that delete only appears when any task is selected?

```
import {Jumbotron, Input, Label, Button, Row, Col, Navbar, NavbarBrand} from 'reactstrap';
import { Control, LocalForm, Errors } from 'react-redux-form';

//for validations
const required = (val) => val && val.length;
const minLength = (len) => (val) => val && (val.length >= len);

class Task extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let email = localStorage.getItem("email")
        if (!email) {
        this.props.history.push("/login")
        }
        this.state = {
            email: email,
            tasks: [],
            todoText: "",
            done: false
        };
    };

    // For todoText (textbox entry)
    onChangeInput = e => {
        this.setState({ todoText: e.target.value });
    }

    //for Adding the task
    onSubmitTodo = (values) => {
        const payload = {
            email: this.state.email
        }
        const todoText = this.state.todoText
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/tasks', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: payload.email,
                tasks: todoText,
            })
        })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return this.setState(({ tasks }) => ({
                        tasks: [...tasks, { id: tasks.length, name: values.todoText, done: false }],
                        todoText: ""
                    }));
                }
                return Promise.reject(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.warn('Something went wrong', error)
            })


    };


    //for using tasks as done or not done
    onChangeBox = item => {
        this.setState(({ tasks }) => ({
            tasks: tasks.map(el =>
                el.id === item.id ? { ...el, done: !el.done } : el)
        }));
    };

    //for deleting selected tasks
    handleDel = item => {
        const payload = {
            email: this.state.email
        }
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/tasks', {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: payload.email,
                tasks: [item.id]
            })
        })

            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return this.setState(({ tasks }) => ({
                        tasks: tasks.filter(el => el.id !== item.id)
                    })),
                        this.componentDidMount();
                }
            })
    };


    componentDidMount() {
        const payload = {
            email: this.state.email
        }
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                let tasks = []
                data.tasks.map((item, index) => {
                    tasks.push({ id: index, name: item, done: false })
                })
                this.setState({ tasks: tasks })
            })
    }

    render() {
        const List = ({ list, onChangeBox, handleDel }) => (
            <ul className='ul'>
                {
                    list.map((item) => (         //list view for todo list
                        < li key={item.id} className="list" style={{ textDecoration: item.done ? "line-through" : "" }}>
                            <Input type="checkbox" onClick={() => onChangeBox(item)} defaultChecked={item.done} style={{ marginRight: 20 }} />
                            {item.name}
                            <span type="button" onClick={() => handleDel(item)} style={{ marginLeft: 50 }} className="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg "></span>
                        </li>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
        );

        const { tasks, todoText } = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                <Navbar dark color='dark'>
                    <div className="container">
                        <span className="fa fa-tasks fa-lg"></span>
                        <NavbarBrand href="/" > To Do
                        <br /> keep your tasks in check </NavbarBrand>
                    </div>
                </Navbar>
                <Jumbotron>
                    <div className="container">
                        <LocalForm onSubmit={(values) => this.onSubmitTodo(values)}>
                            <Row className="form-group">
                                <Label htmlFor="todoText" md={1}><h4>Task</h4></Label>
                                <Col md={3}>
                                    <Control.text model=".todoText" autoComplete="off" value={todoText}
                                        onChange={this.onChangeInput}
                                        validators={{
                                            required, minLength: minLength(1)
                                        }}
                                        className="form-control col-md-3" />
                                    <Errors className="text-danger"
                                        model=".todoText"
                                        show="touched"
                                        messages={{
                                            required: 'required',
                                            minLength: 'Must be Greater than or equal to 1 characters'
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </Col>
                                <Col md={2}>
                                    <Button type="submit" color="success" >
                                        ADD TASK
                                    </Button>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </LocalForm> <br />
                        {tasks.length ? <List list={tasks} onChangeBox={this.onChangeBox} handleDel={this.handleDel} /> : <div className="notask">You don't have any pending tasks...Yay!!!</div>}
                        <Button className="button" >Delete</Button>
                    </div>
                                    </Jumbotron>
            </>
        );
    }
}


export default Task;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is you don't have a way to select multiple tasks because your checkboxes are currently only used for marking and unmarking tasks as completed. You'll need to change how your complete/incomplete logic works if you want to handle deleting multiple tasks via the checkboxes. (I won't cover that in my solution below though, since that isn't what your question is about.)

1. Reorganize your task logic so that the checkboxes are only for *selecting* tasks by changing `onChangeBox` to mark tasks as `selected` instead of `done`.
2. When the "Delete" button is clicked, update your tasks in state by doing the following:

   ```js
   this.setState(({ tasks }) => ({
     tasks: tasks.filter(task => !task.selected)
   }));
   ```

This will allow you to delete one or more tasks, but now you'll have to implement your task completion logic in a different way.

Comment: okay thanks. i'll try to update my code as you said and let you know.

Comment: thanks @Adam this worked. however as i am using a backend here so i need to pass element id to my server in the form of array. i made a method multiDel for delete button and updated state using that button as you suggested. i tried to pass "item" when checkbox is checked by calling this.multiDel(item) but this would delete an item as soon as it is selected. any suggestion how can i achieve this?